# Rails console "password: nil"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not sure if this is a problem but I want to make sure before I proceed with the Michael Hartl rails tutorial. This is the chapter I'm at the end of ( http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-the_first_signup )

He has this

```
$ rails console
>> User.find_by(email: "example@railstutorial.org")
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Rails Tutorial", email: "example@railstutorial.org",
created_at: "2013-03-12 05:51:34", updated_at: "2013-03-12 05:51:34",
password_digest: "$2a$10$A58/j7wwh3aAffGkMAO9Q.jjh3jshd.6akhDKtchAz/R...">
```

I get this

```
$ rails console
>> User.find_by(email: "example@railstutorial.org")
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Foo Bar", email: "example@railstutorial.org", created_at
: "2013-12-08 08:29:45", updated_at: "2013-12-08 08:29:45", password_digest: "$2
a$10$R2bw6s6FIsBtL9WPn21ypua4sWjB.xWeYOojrWj3Idkv...", password: nil>
```

Notice the "password: nil" that I get in my line. He doesn't seem to get that on his? Is this a problem or did I seem to do something wrong?

Additional code or information can be added upon request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the specific example, but it looks fine. Generally you'd expect password to be nil, after retrieving it from the database, as it shouldn't be stored directly in the database. Password digest represents the encrypted form of the password that can be used to check if the password was right when user tries to login.

Rails is showing every attribute. For some reason,  the tutorial example doesn't include a password attribute for the user whereas in your code, it's there. If the DB migration does include a "password" attribute, then you'd expect to see it in the results for this record.

Comment: Appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i am also go with mahemoff that rails default stores password with encrypted format using password digest so can't access directly but you can reset current password with new one and use by rails console help.